# change locale in filter class in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

how to change locale in filter class in springMVC.

in my filter class I'm using below code:

```
LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(new Locale(lang));
```

I'm passing **lang** value is **"ms"**.

when I change locale from UI it is working fine. i want change in filter calss, it is not working.

in my **spring-servlet.xml** below things i configured.

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />    
</bean>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName">
            <value>locale</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

**Web.xml**

        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    classpath:/conf/context/spring-platform.xml 
    classpath:/conf/context/spring-beans.xml 
    classpath:/conf/context/spring-security.xml 
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<filter>
    <filter-name>accessFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>accessFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersy</servlet-name>
    <!-- <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> -->
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- <init-param> <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> 
        <param-value>org.managers</param-value> </init-param> -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        <!-- <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>org.filter.ServiceRequestFilter</param-value>   -->    
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/resources/tlds/spring.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

Noting is happening(Locale is not changing). No Exception in logs or console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using **SessionLocaleResolver** so please try with below code.

```
Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(httpRequest,SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,locale);
```

it will set you locale into session. I think it will resolve your problem .

Comment: +1. Confirming that it works wonders. I'm using a CustomPreAuthenticationFilter that is invoked right after the Spring Security J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter. A user has a profile in which he has the ability to define a preferred language (locale) regardless of its computer locale. This solution did the trick. Thank you @Rajesh.